# Using git revert in this particular scenario

Tags: git, github, version-control, versioning, dvcs

This is what I had:

```
$ ls
file

$ cat file 
change 1
change 2
change 3

$ git log --oneline
8979b76 Add change 3 to file
ff1aead Add change 2 to file
53559fe Add change 1 to file
```

Q1 : This is what I did and what I got:

```
$ git revert 53559fe
error: could not revert 53559fe... Add change 1 to file
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
$ cat file 
change 1
change 2
change 3
```

Why so ?

Q2: Then I did:

```
$ git revert --abort
$ git revert ff1aead
error: could not revert ff1aead... Add change 2 to file
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
$ cat file 
change 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
change 2
change 3
=======
>>>>>>> parent of ff1aead... Add change 2 to file
```

Why did I get an error?

How to interpret the markers in the file ?

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of information about the markers. If you just want to merge, look at [Fix merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git).

---

I'm assuming 'change 1' created the file in question. If that is the case, the first revert fails because before the change the file didn't exist but now it does. What you want is somewhere in between: You probably want a file

```
change 2
change 3
```

This cannot automatically be computed from that. The reason why you don't have any markers is that this conflict does not apply to the contents of the file but the tree. `git mergetool` makes this very clear; it asks you whether you want to keep the file or delete it. In this case you have to keep it and remove the first line.

I guess the second conflict appears because there is not enough context to reliably merge automatically. If you open a 3-way-merge tool you see something like this:

```
   LOCAL |   RESULT |   REMOTE
change 1 |          | change 1
change 2 |          |
change 3 |          |
```

You have to build the result in the middle based on the information in LOCAL and REMOTE which refer to you current state and the state before change 2 got introduced respectively.

Of course, what you want is

```
change 1
change 3
```

but this is not at all obvious from the limited context provided here, is it?